# how to convert double to string in c++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2013, double

So, I have this code in a calculator application. I want it so if the divisor is 0, the program will print "ERROR". I have the console out inside the main function. All I really need help with is converting the Quotient value from double to string. I can't find anything else online that matches my scenario, so can anyone help me out here?

```
double Division(double dividend, double divisor)
{
    double Quotient = dividend / divisor;

    if (divisor == 0) {
        Quotient = "ERROR";
    }

    return Quotient;
}
```

Comment: Two solutions: Either print the error in the function, and return e.g. [`std::nan()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan). Or throw an exception, possibly [`std::invalid_argument`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument). Oh, and do the check *before* you do the actual division.

Comment: What you're asking about isn't converting the value from `double` to `string`. You want `Quotient`, which is a variable of type `double`, to suddenly become a variable of type `string`. Not possible in C++.

Comment: It's really not clear what your question is. You say what you want to do, but not what's stopping you from doing it or what goes wrong when you try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just print out an error message with a string and return back to your input/function call?